# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot find or start my wireless adapter in terminal

Tags: 16.04, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

After attempting to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 my system freezes after login.  I do not have a network so need my wireless so I can try / updating / upgrading and anything else to try and fix problem.  I can get into command line using ctl alt f2 ok. lspci shows my wireless as Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01) but iwconfig shows lo no wireless extensions - there is no wlan0.  I want to be able to start my wifi so I can try and fix the errors that seem to have happened during the upgrade - thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered that my Wi-Fi is called `wlp19s0`, apparently they changed the naming conventions.

I tried connecting but got (7) secrets were required but not provided

Then I tried

```
nmcli r wifi off to turn off
nmcli r wifi on to turn on
```

and

```
nmcli dev wifi con "wifi name" password "wifi password"
```

including the `"`s.

This then gave me an error

```
ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
```

but I tried it and it was connected and working anyway.

Comment: Wifi and ethernet names have been renamed, for wifi, you will see `wlp<number>s<another_number>` and for ethernet, this something like `enp<number>s<another_number>`